# How to get grep string output to array elements in bash

Tags: bash, grep

I currently have the code

```
descarray=($(grep -oP "(?<=description\"\:)(.*?)(?=\}})" descfile.json))
```

but when I try this I get the match correctly but since it is a string with whitespace, it separates each word as element in array.

Example of string that match would be:

```
"*No_Request_Validation* issue exists @ some other information here""another example goes here"
```

but what I would get is

```
"*No_Request_Validation*
issue
exists
@
some
...
```

There are quotes at the start and at the end of each required elements and I would like to separate them with it.
for example:

```
descarray[0]: "*No_Request_Validation* issue exists @ some other information here"
descarray[1]: "another example goes here"
```

Comment: with jq something like `jq .[].description descfile.json` might be more robust

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're running up against wordsplitting, which splits tokens on `IFS`, which includes newlines, tabs and spaces by default. To read the output of grep into an array split by newlines, consider `mapfile`:

```
mapfile -t descarray < <(grep -oP "(?<=description\"\:)(.*?)(?=\}})" descfile.json))
```

For example,

```
$ mapfile -t foo <<< '1 2 3
4 5 6'
$ echo "${#foo[@]}"  # we should see two members in the array
2
$ echo "${foo[1]}"  # The second member should be '4 5 6'
4 5 6
```

(Note the use of [process substitution](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution) instead of a pipe. This is important to prevent an implicit subshell from eating your `descarray` variable.)

You can read more about mapfile in your local bash using `help mapfile`, or in the [Bash reference manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html).

Comment: Do I need to create an empty array before running this command or is that not necessary?

Comment: If you need to parse json data, I'd strongly recommend to use the `jq` command.

Comment: @EDK It's not necessary to create an empty array first.